# setting up sharepoint 2010 team development environment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, admin

I wanted to know,

if, I can setup sharepoint 2010 server along with visual studio 2010. And sql-server on another machine in some domain
and
**create multiple accounts on the sharepoint 2010 machine 
and allow developers to develop sharepoint projects on the same machine with those accounts**.

Also I wanted to know about version controls system like svn availability for sharepoint 2010.

Comment: SharePoint projects are supported by TFS, including automated builds and deployments.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. But the highlighted part is more crucial for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in our company each developer has own development server, but some time we work simultaneously on the same server. I don't know why you need separate slq server, for development purposes SharePoint works fine with SQL express installed on the same machine. But if you wish you can use separate SQL server of course. If you would like to use specific accounts for SharePoint it is a good practice. Look at [this post](http://www.ericharlan.com/Moss_SharePoint_2007_Blog/sharepoint-2010-service-account-reference-guide-a184.html), there is some information about typical SharePoint accounts pool.

About simultaneous development. If you work with Visual Studio, not configuration, when you are deploying solutions server will restart IIS each time, is is not so useful for normal development of few employees. Also if you will decide to work like this, my advice to work in different web applications for each developer it will allow you more useful debug capabilities. You will not interrupt each other because of attaching to the same process w3wp. But notice, SharePoint is flexible and extendable environment, you can do I lot of things just with configuration and JavaScript development by SharePoint Designer. So if you will work most of time by configuring it will be possible successfully work on the same server for whole team.

About source control. If you are developing with Visual Studio, TFS is for you, or any other source control system, like svn or git. If you are develping by configuring with SharePoint Designer, I advice you to store some reusable functionality also withing TFS, by just copying. For other content you can turn on versioning on SharePoint libraries, so each your modification will be stored with comments if you wish.

Comment: Please press [ENTER] twice between paragraphs so they are separated properly in the result.

Comment: What do you mean about results? I'm not so long time on stackoverflow, please describe me.

Comment: I mean in the answer as displayed here.

Comment: Are there any recommended/guidelines approach for solution development in SharePoint 2010

Comment: There are a lot of information in Internet, but from custom development point of view is SharePoint Guidance 2010 from Patterns and Practices. Check this link http://spg.codeplex.com/releases and download PDF